# Encrypt hex using AES128-ECB and maintain big endian in javascript/node

Tags: react-native, encryption, aes, endianness, ecb

I am trying to encrypt hex using AES128-ECB using the Big Endian protocol.

I know that ECB is not secure but it is something that I need to use to connect with a Bluetooth application.

I am building a React-Native application that will connect to a Bluetooth peripheral.

I am using the aes-js npm module.

My code so far is:

```
    const key = Buffer.from("20572F52364B3F473050415811632D2B", "hex")
    const text = '0x060x010x010x01'
    const textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(text);
    console.log('textBytes: ', textBytes)

    const aesEcb = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ecb(key);
    console.log('aesEcb: ', aesEcb)
    const encryptedBytes = aesEcb.encrypt(textBytes);
    console.log('encryptedBytes: ', encryptedBytes)

    const encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
    console.log('encryptedHex: ', encryptedHex);
```

I don't think that this is maintaining big-endian.

I would love some help please.

Comment: What do you mean by maintaining big-endian? Endianness is a way to order multi-byte numbers in memory. What exactly do you want to maintain? AES does a reversible transformation of 16-byte blocks of data into another 16-byte block. What is the expected result you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to know if my code above uses the big endian network byte order or not. Is network byte order either big or little endian or can it be some other network byte order?

Comment: Byte order is only relevant when you take 2, 4, or 8 bytes and interpret them as (u)int16, (u)int32, or (u)int64, respectively (or store a value of one of these types in 2, 4, or 8 bytes). This code doesn't "use" any byte order, because it doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @peter. If i needed to use aesjs.utils.utf16.toBytes() instead of aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes() would I need to do something to maintain Byte order? Do you know what I would need to add to my code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to encrypt hex using AES128-ECB using the Big Endian protocol.

Big endian is a method of mapping numbers to bits / bytes. With big endian, the most significant part is to the left (low index) while with little endian it is to the right (high index). Bytes are generally seen as atomic and don't have an explicit order (generally the highest bit is shown to the left, **but** the index is from high to low instead of from low to high, so they are little endian, just to make things interesting). Characters only have an endianess assigned to the if they are encoded as a multi-byte number.

But UTF-8 and AES have an explicit byte order that doesn't include any number encoding. As such, big or little endianness doesn't come into play. AES internally may operate on 32 bit values, however that doesn't matter when the output is well defined; AES operates as AES, and that's the end of it. It only is a problem if a low level routine returns 32 or 16 bit words instead of bytes.

The `utf16` codec in CryptoJS seems to use UTF-16BE (big endian), and AES won't change that order after encryption / decryption. Note that I have not read this specifically, but since there is also a `utf16le` I think that there aren't that many other options.